# Deleting row from WebGrid hits controller twice(Clearing parameter data) MVC, JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

I have run through quite a few posts and tried and tested and nothing has worked, or I have missed something completely, but I have this feeling my situation is not related any of these other posts. I am relatively new to MVC and have no idea what the cause of this issue is.

Problem : I am deleting an item in a WebGrid. I have a confirmation box and if Yes is clicked, it deletes the item, but then the controller is hit twice, clearing a parameter I am passing to display an alert(This parameter is used to display success on new and edit and fail on error. However, the item is being deleted, but no success alert as parameter value is being lost when Index ActionResult is fired a 2nd time.

What am I doing wrong ?

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index(PipelineDetails model, int id, string Result)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        //PipelineViewModel PL = new PipelineViewModel();
        PipelineDetails PL = new PipelineDetails();
        ProjectManager PM = new ProjectManager();

        PL.fkiProjectID = id;

        PipeList = PM.GetPipelineList(id);
        PL.PipelineListmodel = PipeList;

        foreach (var item in PipeList)
        {
            PL.fkiProjectID = item.fkiProjectID;
            PL.pkiPipeline = item.pkiPipeline;

            if (Result == null)
            {
                PL.Result = "";
            }
            else
            {
                PL.Result = Result;
            }
        }

        return View(PL);
    }

public ActionResult Delete_PipelineInfo(PipelineDetails_Delete model)
    {
        string Result = "";
        ProjectManager PM = new ProjectManager();

        int ProjectID = model.fkiProjectID;
        //Update model to DB
        Result = PM.DeletePipeLineSingle(model.fkiProjectID, model.pkiPipeline);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pipeline", new { id = ProjectID, result = Result });
    }
```

JSON in View :

```
$(function () {
            $('.edit-mode').hide();
            $('.delete-user').on('click', function () {
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                var PLID = tr.find("#pkiPipeline").html();
                var PLAccumulated_Length = tr.find("#Accumulated_Length").val();
                var PLElevation = tr.find("#Elevation").val();
                var PLPipe_Outside_Diameter = tr.find("#Pipe_Outside_Diameter").val();
                var PLWall_Thickness = tr.find("#Wall_Thickness").val();
                var PLControl_Point_Description = tr.find("#Control_Point_Description").val();
                var PLControl_Point_Size = tr.find("#Control_Point_Size").val();
                var PLProjectID = tr.find(".fkiProjectID").val();

                var PipelineDetails =
                {
                    "pkiPipeline": PLID,
                    "fkiProjectID": PLProjectID
                };
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Pipeline item?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Pipeline/Delete_PipelineInfo',
                        data: JSON.stringify(PipelineDetails),
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (data) {
                            window.location.href = "/Pipeline/Index/" + PLProjectID;
                        }

                    })
                }
            });
        });
```

WebGrid :

```
<div id="gridContent" style="font-family: Arial; padding: 20px; overflow:auto;height:380px" class="col-md-12">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns:
        grid.Columns(
         grid.Column("pkiPipeline", "Node Nr.", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode">@item.pkiPipeline </span> <label id="pkiPipeline" class="edit-mode">@item.pkiPipeline</label> </text>, style: "col1Width"),
         grid.Column("Accumulated_Length", "Accumulated Length", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAccumulated_Length">@item.Accumulated_Length</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Accumulated_Length" value="@item.Accumulated_Length" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Elevation", "Elevation", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblElevation">@item.Elevation</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Elevation" value="@item.Elevation" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Pipe_Outside_Diameter", "Pipe Outside Diameter", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblPipe_Outside_Diameter">@item.Pipe_Outside_Diameter</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Pipe_Outside_Diameter" value="@item.Pipe_Outside_Diameter" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Wall_Thickness", "Wall Thickness", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblWall_Thickness">@item.Wall_Thickness</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Wall_Thickness" value="@item.Wall_Thickness" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Control_Point_Description", "Control Point Description", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblControl_Point_Description">@item.Control_Point_Description</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Control_Point_Description" value="@item.Control_Point_Description" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Control_Point_Size", "Control Point Size", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblControl_Point_Size">@item.Control_Point_Size</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Control_Point_Size" value="@item.Control_Point_Size" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("", format: @<text>
                <input type="hidden" class="fkiProjectID" value="@item.fkiProjectID" />
                <div class="container" style="width:120px">
                    <div class="btn-group-xs">
                        <button data-loading-text="Loading..." class="edit-user display-mode btn btn-default2" autocomplete="off">Edit</button>
                        <button class="delete-user display-mode btn btn-default2">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </text>, style: "col3Width", canSort: false)
       ))
</div>
```

Comment: You doing a redirect in your ajax callback. There is no point using ajax if you want to redirect. What are you trying to do with this code. And what is the element with `.delete-user`? If its a link or submit button, you have not cancelled its default action

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The delete-user is the delete button on the WebGrid, I have updated my post to include it. This is code I found and that sort of seemed to work, but obviously not completely - So what I want to do is, click on the Delete button on the WebGrid, Confirmation pops up "Do you want to delete" and then on clicking yes, delete the data(provided in the controller) and refresh the WebGrid and display the successful bootstrap alert. What is the right way of doing it as removing the redirect then does nothing and doesnt even hit my controller ?

Comment: What is the right way of doing this ? Anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. I have posted the code below in case it helps someone else in future. This might not be the "right" way, as I am still new to all of this, but this worked for me - So I hope it helps someone else!

Cheers!

Controller :

```
public JsonResult Delete_PipelineInfo(PipelineDetails model)
    {
        String DeleteResult = String.Empty;
        String result = String.Empty;

        PipelineDetails PL = new PipelineDetails();
        ProjectManager PM = new ProjectManager();

        PL.fkiProjectID = model.fkiProjectID;

        PipeList = PM.GetPipelineList(model.fkiProjectID);
        PL.PipelineListmodel = PipeList;

        PipelineDetails PD = PipeList.Find(p => p.pkiPipeline == model.pkiPipeline && p.fkiProjectID == model.fkiProjectID);
        if (PD != null)
        {
            PipeList.Remove(PD);
            result = "1";
            DeleteResult = PM.DeletePipeLineSingle(model.fkiProjectID, model.pkiPipeline);
        }
        else
            result = "0";

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JSON :

```
$('.delete-user').on('click', function () {
                if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this Pipeline item?")) {
                    var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');

                    var PLID = tr.find("#pkiPipeline").html();
                    var PLAccumulated_Length = tr.find("#Accumulated_Length").val();
                    var PLElevation = tr.find("#Elevation").val();
                    var PLPipe_Outside_Diameter = tr.find("#Pipe_Outside_Diameter").val();
                    var PLWall_Thickness = tr.find("#Wall_Thickness").val();
                    var PLControl_Point_Description = tr.find("#Control_Point_Description").val();
                    var PLControl_Point_Size = tr.find("#Control_Point_Size").val();
                    var PLProjectID = tr.find(".fkiProjectID").val();
                    var PLResult = "Delete Success";

                    var PipelineDetails =
                    {
                        "pkiPipeline": PLID,
                        "Accumulated_Length": PLAccumulated_Length,
                        "Elevation": PLElevation,
                        "Pipe_Outside_Diameter": PLPipe_Outside_Diameter,
                        "Wall_Thickness": PLWall_Thickness,
                        "Control_Point_Description": PLControl_Point_Description,
                        "Control_Point_Size": PLControl_Point_Size,
                        "fkiProjectID": PLProjectID,
                        "Result" : PLResult
                    };


                    $.ajax({

                        url: '/Pipeline/Delete_PipelineInfo/',
                        data: JSON.stringify(PipelineDetails),
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (result) {
                            isSuccess = result;
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            isSuccess = result;
                        }
                    }).done(function () {
                        if (isSuccess == "1") {           // Successfully Deleted
                            //alert("Successfully Deleted");
                            //location.reload();      // refresh the page
                            window.location.href = "/Pipeline/Index/" + PLProjectID + "?result=" + PLResult;
                        }
                        else {                      // Data Error
                            alert("Error. Please, check the data");
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
```

Switch for Alerts + WebGrid :

```
@model AirFlo_Size_Programme.Models.PipelineDetails

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Pipe Line";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_ProjectFlow.cshtml";
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.PipelineListmodel, canPage: false);
}

@switch (Model.Result)
{
case "Success":
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="pipelinesuccess">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Saved!</strong> Pipeline added successfully.
    </div>
    break;
    case "False":@*This means that no result has been passed so no Action is required*@
case "":
case null:
break;
case "Delete Success":
<div class="alert alert-success" id="pipelineDeleteSuccess">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Deleted!</strong> Pipeline deleted successfully.
</div>
    break;
    case "Edit Success":
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="pipelineDeleteSuccess">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Saved!</strong> Pipeline Edited successfully.
    </div>
    break;
default:
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="pipelinefailed">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Failed!</strong> The following error occurred : @Model.Result
    </div>
    break;
}

<div id="gridContent" style="font-family: Arial; padding: 20px; overflow:auto;height:380px" class="col-md-12">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns:
        grid.Columns(
         grid.Column("pkiPipeline", "Node Nr.", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode">@item.pkiPipeline </span> <label id="pkiPipeline" class="edit-mode">@item.pkiPipeline</label> </text>, style: "col1Width"),
         grid.Column("Accumulated_Length", "Accumulated Length", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAccumulated_Length">@item.Accumulated_Length</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Accumulated_Length" value="@item.Accumulated_Length" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Elevation", "Elevation", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblElevation">@item.Elevation</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Elevation" value="@item.Elevation" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Pipe_Outside_Diameter", "Pipe Outside Diameter", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblPipe_Outside_Diameter">@item.Pipe_Outside_Diameter</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Pipe_Outside_Diameter" value="@item.Pipe_Outside_Diameter" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Wall_Thickness", "Wall Thickness", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblWall_Thickness">@item.Wall_Thickness</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Wall_Thickness" value="@item.Wall_Thickness" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Control_Point_Description", "Control Point Description", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblControl_Point_Description">@item.Control_Point_Description</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Control_Point_Description" value="@item.Control_Point_Description" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Control_Point_Size", "Control Point Size", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblControl_Point_Size">@item.Control_Point_Size</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Control_Point_Size" value="@item.Control_Point_Size" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("", format: @<text>
                <input type="hidden" class="fkiProjectID" value="@item.fkiProjectID" />
                <div class="container" style="width:120px">
                    <div class="btn-group-xs">
                        <button data-loading-text="Loading..." class="edit-user display-mode btn btn-default2" autocomplete="off">Edit</button>
                        <button class="delete-user display-mode btn btn-default2">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </text>, style: "col3Width", canSort: false)
       ))
</div>
```